# I recommend your reading this question

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I remember that we have learnt a structure, what has always been really strange to me. We can say that "I recommend to do something" However in the *strange structure* we can say something like(I am not sure): "I suggest you(/your) not being here". So it is built up:

```
[object] [verb] [indirect object] [gerund]
```

I am not sure that it was exactly like this, but I am eager to find out how it is called, when to use it and if I can use with all kinds of verbs. I hope your figuring this out.

Comment: Don't you have an elsewhere to be? Very Buffy the Vampire slayeresque

Comment: 'We can say that "I recommend to do something to you" '. Really? Can you think of an example that would sound acceptable? There are very few examples, for instance, for "I recommend to leave him" on Google (and _they_ are not very authoritative-sounding).

Comment: That's not `[object]`, but rather `[subject]`. I.e, _I_ is the **Subject** of the `[verb]` _suggest_. And how do you know that's an `[indirect object]`, anyway? This is a question about gerund complements, which are not strange structures; they're very common. And Edward's correct about the ungrammaticality of using _recommend_ with a subjectless gerund complement. [This may be of use](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf); or it may not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you read first about the so-called 'simple catenative' structures in English ( http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs ), and then check on the 'complex catenative' construction (Huddleston & Pullum).

There has been an extensive debate on the actual cases involving *recommend* as the 'lead' (catenating) verb at http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21740 . Complex catenation:

> recommend somebody to do something: *We'd recommend you to book your
>   flight early*.

is licensed by [oxfordlearnersdictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/recommend)

but the structure using a that-clause ( *We'd recommend that you book your flight early*. ) sounds far more idiomatic to me. *We'd advise you to book your  flight early*. is, on the other hand, totally idiomatic.

*We recommend your (gerund)* is quite a common construction, arguably catenative (how 'verby' are gerunds?) (that they are quite 'nouny' is indicated by the fact that 'your', 'her' etc are often used with them):

> We do recommend your leaving the gauze over the surgery site... (Google)

Comment: 'We recommend your (gerund) is quite a common construction' can I use this construction with all the verbs with indirect objects?

Comment: You're confusing analyses. Have a look at Cobuild's fine treatment (with lists of verbs) at https://arts-ccr-002.bham.ac.uk/ccr/patgram/ch01.html (section 7): 'V -ing: The verb is followed by an '-ing' form. This pattern has three structures: >Structure I: Verbs in phase (i.e. complex verb groups) She started walking. > **Structure II: Verb with [direct] Object He liked dancing with her.** >Structure III: Verb with Adjunct They ended up fighting. There are the following meaning groups for each structure: I.1 The 'start' and 'stop' group (begin, cease, come, commence, continue, discontinue...'

Comment: For the distinction between say 'I liked his singing last night' and 'I liked him singing last night', see Ken Greenwald's answer at  http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6275&p=32350#p32350 . Also, at http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23581&hilit=gerund+Quirk&start=15 is a discussion of the 'noun? verb? both? a bit of each? neither?' debates surrounding -ing forms.

Comment: That's not an indirect object. Things are not as simple as you think. There are [many, many different kinds of verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/levin.verbs2.txt), each with their own set of rules that they must use, or they must not use, or they may use.

Comment: Oh, and as for gerunds themselves, they're one of the [at 5 different usages](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) of the _-ing_ suffix.